# How to check dataframe column that contains value lower than 2500

Tags: python, data-science

I want to check how many values are lower than 2500

1)Using .count(

```py
df[df.price<2500]["price"].count()
```

2. Using .values_counts()

```py
df[df.price<2500]["price"].value_counts()
```

[this ise code view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vv0u.jpg)

First one results 27540 and second 2050. Which one is correct count?

Comment: You shouldn't post your code as a link but rather display it properly here

Comment: Sorry but it is not really clear, what you are asking for. Do you want to know, how many rows have a price less than 2500? It is a bit difficult to follow you.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not 2050, analyze your histogram.

The method `value_counts` will assign only one row for a number that has duplicates but it will associate the number of duplicates. So it seems to be 2050 differents prices, but if you count duplicates there are much more.

Comment: thank you. I should have used the count method